# making a <ul> list creates a ekstra bulletpoint

Tags: html

I have a pice of code that creates the list shown bellow.

- home
- 
- page2
- page3

I want to remove the unused dot, and understand where it is coming from.

```html
<ul>
  <li>Home
    <li>
      <li><a href="page2.html"> page2 </a></li>
      <li><a href="page3.html"> page3 </a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Code formatting helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second open `<li>` signifies a new `<li>` nested within another, hence, an empty bullet point.

It is a syntax error, and must be a `</li>` rather than a `<li>`

```
<doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
    <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li><a href = "page2.html"> page2 </a></li>
    <li><a href = "page3.html"> page3 </a></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you forgot to close

```
<li>
```

It should be:

```
<li>Home</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<li>` with only the opening tag is perfectly valid, when this is followed by another `<li>` or by any ending tag.

In your case the second `<li>` creates a new empty bulletpoint as browsers see your code like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>Home
    {</li>}<li>
      {</li>}<li><a href="page2.html"> page2 </a></li>
      <li><a href="page3.html"> page3 </a></li>
</ul>
```

The `{</li>}`'s (without {}) are the tags what browsers add before next starting tag to end previous `<li>` elements.

The same is true for example for `<p>` as well.

More information: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#optional-tags